# How to derive the hierarchy output using SAP HANA SQL

Tags: python, sql, hana

I came across some below hierarchical requirement. I have two columns called `COL1` and `COL2` and want to derive the value (`MAP`).

`COL1` and `COL2` have 4 types of relationships i.e. 1:1, 1:M, M:1, M:M.

Explanation - For example

1. XX1 is mapped to A1 (temp result XX1 : A1)
2. A1 is mapped to XX3 (temp result XX1, XX3 : A1)
3. A1 is mapped to XX3 (temp result XX1, XX3 : A1)
4. XX3 is mapped to A8 (temp result XX1, XX3 : A1, A8)
5. A8 is mapped to XX9 (temp result XX1, XX3, XX9 : A1, A8)

Note - Traverse level not fixed, it can be any levels.

SQL solution is more preferred and Python solution is least preferred (in case of Python, I want to read the data from the file as I can't connect to DB through Python).

Is there anyway to achieve?

```
COL1    COL2    Map
XX1     A1      XX1,XX3,XX9 : A1,A8
XX2     A2      XX2,XX4 : A2
XX3     A1      XX1,XX3,XX9 : A1,A8
XX4     A2      XX2,XX4 : A2
XX5     A3      XX5:A3
XX6     A4      XX5:A4,A5
XX6     A5      XX5:A4,A5
XX7     A6      XX7,XX8:A6:A7
XX7     A7      XX7,XX8:A6:A7
XX8     A6      XX7,XX8:A6:A7
XX8     A7      XX7,XX8:A6:A7
XX3     A8      XX1,XX3,XX9 : A1,A8
XX9     A8      XX1,XX3,XX9 : A1,A8
```

I have attached the sample data as an image as well.

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sn4D.png)

Comment: From your explanation above, I understand that the result is sensitive to the sorting of the input table. Is this understanding correct? If yes, what is the sorting criteria and how do you ensure correct sorting?